# How do I add a tablesorter action to a function

Tags: jquery, function, widget, tablesorter, zebra-striping

When creating a function that has 2 actions, one is a return confirm, the other is applywidgets from tablesorter.

Do I need to reference/load tablesorter in the function before `.trigger('applyWidgets');`

Answer (score 0):

In a comment I added to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275709/tablesorter-zebra-not-working-after-deleting-a-row), I shared that when you use `return confirm()`, any code below that `return` will be ignored. Use `confirm` without the `return` in front of it.

The triggered "applyWidgets" does not need any reference to tablesorter. Nothing will happen to the table if tablesorter isn't already applied, and no error will occur.

```
function yeah() {
    confirm('Are you sue you want to delete?');
    $("#receipts").trigger('applyWidgets');
    return false;
}
```